# Sharepoint warning threshold

Tags: sharepoint-online, threshold

I'm using O365 and I've created a list which I know will have well over 5k in items.  I'm getting the threshold warning message stating my list is at 3.5k and the limit for threshold throttling is 5k.

Is this a generic warning message? - as I've indexed most fields, and also ensured that all my views have appropriate filters using the index fields.

I'm under the impression this warning message goes away if you take the right steps, the trouble is I'm sure I have, yet Microsoft can't seem to help me with it.

Just want to know if this is a generic message to everyone when they get close to 5k or not?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a generic warning message. It triggers based on count of items in the list, regardless of Views/Indexes, and so on.

Comment: Spent hours looking around for that answer, and 30 minutes to Microsoft support - and then a dog walk this evening and I thought, I'll ask that new community I've joined - thanks Trevor.

Answer (score 0):

The warning in the list settings appears when the item count gets near the system threshold. The 5000 rule relates to how much data can be returned to any given view in that list/library. Folders are another way to slice up the pie to reset the count of values returned to a view. Also indexing and filtering are helpful as well.

Here is a good article that explains all of this https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-overcome-sharepoint-5000-item-limit-threshold/